# Creating an iOS application which is distributed to limited selected audience

Tags: iphone, ios

I just started creating custom client application for IOS, Which i have already developed for PC and Android clients. Idea of these apps is to use SQLite database file, which is created in PC admin app and is actualized by Internet. Development of this application is payed from one company and shoud be distributed to selected group of people.

What i want to ask is how to distribute this IOS application to certain audience of people (who has right to use it)? Should I put it on app store as free app without database file which should be downloaded to iphone from secret site?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do it is via the [iOS Developer Enterprise Program.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/)

As for the data, you could link it to a web API if the data is growing or changing regularly. But for static data, you could distribute it by including it in the application itself. See [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) and other tools for more information.

You can also release it for free on App Store and provide a custom login. However, this is not recommended as this application is useless for the rest of the world. The only reason you would want to do this is if your custom clients can register on your website or some place else and you want to allow them to access the app. This is generally done for subscription based applications. But I presume yours is not such a case.

There is also Ad Hoc distribution, but with that you are limited to 100 devices.

[You can read more about distribution.](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html)

Answer (score 1):

Note: this may not be the bust way but here is my solution for it

I established a server and set user credentials on the server before, i share credentials with the client and he/she logs in with them.. Later they can edit their credentials, my app is on the store for any body but someone who doesnt have those credentials can't log in..

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is this:

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Answer (score 0):

An ad-hoc distribution is your solution.

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html

If you're planning to distribute the app to more than 100 people, go for their Enterprise program:

https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/